# NullPointerException in Apache MINA on Android 2.2

Tags: java, serialization, android-2.2-froyo, apache-mina

I'm developing an application for android using Apache MINA 2.0.4. It is working good on all versions I have tested, but 2.2.2 on HTC Desire.

The client manages to connect to the server but once the server sends a message I get a NullPointerException:

```
04-16 13:45:25.992: E/EXCEPTION(18456): NETWORK
04-16 13:45:25.992: E/EXCEPTION(18456): org.apache.mina.filter.codec.ProtocolDecoderException: java.lang.NullPointerException (Hexdump: 00 00 00 32 AC ED 00 05 73 72 01 00 25 63 6F 6D 2E 62 6F 6C 6C 73 2E 73 68 61 72 65 64 2E 77 77 77 2E 48 69 67 68 4C 65 76 65 6C 4D 65 73 73 61 67 65 78 70 28 70)
04-16 13:45:25.992: E/EXCEPTION(18456):     at org.apache.mina.filter.codec.ProtocolCodecFilter.messageReceived(ProtocolCodecFilter.java:251)
04-16 13:45:25.992: E/EXCEPTION(18456):     at org.apache.mina.core.filterchain.DefaultIoFilterChain.callNextMessageReceived(DefaultIoFilterChain.java:434)
04-16 13:45:25.992: E/EXCEPTION(18456):     at org.apache.mina.core.filterchain.DefaultIoFilterChain.access$1200(DefaultIoFilterChain.java:46)
04-16 13:45:25.992: E/EXCEPTION(18456):     at org.apache.mina.core.filterchain.DefaultIoFilterChain$EntryImpl$1.messageReceived(DefaultIoFilterChain.java:796)
04-16 13:45:25.992: E/EXCEPTION(18456):     at org.apache.mina.core.filterchain.IoFilterAdapter.messageReceived(IoFilterAdapter.java:119)
04-16 13:45:25.992: E/EXCEPTION(18456):     at org.apache.mina.core.filterchain.DefaultIoFilterChain.callNextMessageReceived(DefaultIoFilterChain.java:434)
04-16 13:45:25.992: E/EXCEPTION(18456):     at org.apache.mina.core.filterchain.DefaultIoFilterChain.fireMessageReceived(DefaultIoFilterChain.java:426)
04-16 13:45:25.992: E/EXCEPTION(18456):     at org.apache.mina.core.polling.AbstractPollingIoProcessor.read(AbstractPollingIoProcessor.java:715)
04-16 13:45:25.992: E/EXCEPTION(18456):     at org.apache.mina.core.polling.AbstractPollingIoProcessor.process(AbstractPollingIoProcessor.java:668)
04-16 13:45:25.992: E/EXCEPTION(18456):     at org.apache.mina.core.polling.AbstractPollingIoProcessor.process(AbstractPollingIoProcessor.java:657)
04-16 13:45:25.992: E/EXCEPTION(18456):     at org.apache.mina.core.polling.AbstractPollingIoProcessor.access$600(AbstractPollingIoProcessor.java:68)
04-16 13:45:25.992: E/EXCEPTION(18456):     at org.apache.mina.core.polling.AbstractPollingIoProcessor$Processor.run(AbstractPollingIoProcessor.java:1141)
04-16 13:45:25.992: E/EXCEPTION(18456):     at org.apache.mina.util.NamePreservingRunnable.run(NamePreservingRunnable.java:64)
04-16 13:45:25.992: E/EXCEPTION(18456):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1068)
04-16 13:45:25.992: E/EXCEPTION(18456):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:561)
04-16 13:45:25.992: E/EXCEPTION(18456):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1102)
04-16 13:45:25.992: E/EXCEPTION(18456): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
04-16 13:45:25.992: E/EXCEPTION(18456):     at java.io.ObjectStreamField.resolve(ObjectStreamField.java:351)
04-16 13:45:25.992: E/EXCEPTION(18456):     at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNewClassDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1863)
04-16 13:45:25.992: E/EXCEPTION(18456):     at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readClassDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:826)
04-16 13:45:25.992: E/EXCEPTION(18456):     at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNewObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2066)
04-16 13:45:25.992: E/EXCEPTION(18456):     at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonPrimitiveContent(ObjectInputStream.java:929)
04-16 13:45:25.992: E/EXCEPTION(18456):     at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2285)
04-16 13:45:25.992: E/EXCEPTION(18456):     at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2240)
04-16 13:45:25.992: E/EXCEPTION(18456):     at org.apache.mina.core.buffer.AbstractIoBuffer.getObject(AbstractIoBuffer.java:2215)
04-16 13:45:25.992: E/EXCEPTION(18456):     at org.apache.mina.filter.codec.serialization.ObjectSerializationDecoder.doDecode(ObjectSerializationDecoder.java:92)
04-16 13:45:25.992: E/EXCEPTION(18456):     at org.apache.mina.filter.codec.CumulativeProtocolDecoder.decode(CumulativeProtocolDecoder.java:178)
04-16 13:45:25.992: E/EXCEPTION(18456):     at org.apache.mina.filter.codec.ProtocolCodecFilter.messageReceived(ProtocolCodecFilter.java:241)
04-16 13:45:25.992: E/EXCEPTION(18456):     ... 15 more
```

I'm using the ObjectSerializationCodecFactory and can't figure out what's wrong. I have tried to use "regular" Java Serialization on Android 2.2 and that worked.

Here is the code for the connection:

```
    NioSocketConnector tConnector = new NioSocketConnector();

    tConnector.setConnectTimeoutMillis(CONNECT_TIMEOUT);
    tConnector.getFilterChain().addLast("codec", new ProtocolCodecFilter(new ObjectSerializationCodecFactory()));
    tConnector.setHandler(new ClientHandler());

    try{
        ConnectFuture future = tConnector.connect(new InetSocketAddress(HOSTNAME, PORT));
        future.awaitUninterruptibly();
        mSession = future.getSession();
        Globals.hideDialog();
    }catch (RuntimeIoException e){
        Globals.hideDialog();
        Globals.showConnectionErrorDialog("Failed to connect to server");
    }

    // wait until the summation is done
    if(mSession != null)
        mSession.getCloseFuture().awaitUninterruptibly();
    tConnector.dispose();
```

The exception is caught in the handler, before messageReceived is called.

Any info about this exception is appreciated!

Thank you

Comment: in this page you will find some help.
i meet this problem ,and i change all the field to non primitive and it work fine.
http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/harmony-commits/201002.mbox/%3C139665626.67221265373510425.JavaMail.jira@brutus.apache.org%3E

Answer (score 0):

I think ClientHandler() is interface. You need to try BasicClientHandler().

Comment: ClientHandler is a class created by me that extends IoHandlerAdapter